# temporary url for java servelt generated image

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, tomcat

i have a servlet that **takes parameters** and  produce a image with username and other information about user used to display image in a html page.

i want to provide a **TEMPORARY URL FOR 1-2 MINUTES** so that it can be opened again this time **without need to pass parameters**

i want a url just for 2-3 minutes,after that no need.
HOW can i do this with ****image caching with server **** or **any other** method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your servlet save the image on disk, in a specific directory, under a automatically generated name (using a counter for example: 23.jpg), and generate the following temporary URL for this servlet: `/tempImage/23.jpg`.

Have another servlet called TempImageServlet mapped to /tempImage/*.

When a request comes in to the TempImageServlet, extract the part after /tempImage/ in the URL used to invoke the servlet: this gives the file name to load. Read the file from the disk. If its creation date is older than 2 minutes, then send an error code in the response. Otherwise, read the file from the disk and send it to the servlet response.

You could have one of the servlets regularly scan the disk for old files and delete them.